# Complex port connection in Verilog

Tags: verilog

Please help to understand the following syntax of verilog port definition.

```
module same_port (.a(i), .b(i)); 
// Name ’i’ is declared inside themodule as a inout port.
// Names ’a’ and ’b’ are
// defined for port connections.
```

Is this connection legal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is legal.  It looks like you took this example straight from section 23.2.2.1  of the [standard](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) (Non-ANSI style port declarations).  As it says there you have two ports `a` and `b` which are both connected to internal net `i`.  When you instantiate this module you can use named port connections to connect two different things to `i`:

```
same_port inst(.a(connection1), .b(connection2));
```

In the above instantiation, both `connection1`  and `connection2` will be connected to `inst.i`.

Even though this is  legal, I would advise against using it unless you have a good reason to.  This is not very commonly used syntax and could cause confusion for someone else looking at your code.  The only place I have seen this is in a verilog netlist automatically generated from an schematic.

Comment: SystemVerilog 3.1a is really old. Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) instead. Section is the same: 23.2.2.1 _Non-ANSI style port declarations_

Comment: @Greg thanks for catching that. I meant to provide a link to 1800-2012 (and my answer is based on it). That link is in the tag wiki and should probably be removed.